# Passing parameters to a DOS batch file called from HTML

Tags: html, parameters, batch-file, dos

I have one question about executing a batch file which is linked via an HREF from a HTML page.

Till now I have the link to the batch file and it's executed without problems if I click on the link

```
> <a HREF="file://///hostname/folder/dosbatch.bat">Call dos batch</a>
```

This works fine.

Now I want to extend this to:

```
> <a HREF="file://///hostname/folder/dosbatch.bat para1">Call dos batch with para</a>
```

With this string, I get the error "The page cannot be displayed"

I allready tried several combinations with %22, %20, single quotes, double quotes and so on, but with no success

Has any one a hint for me ?

Thanks in advance,

Zirod

Comment: this won't work. Something like CGI, PHP, JSP, ASP will help you.

Comment: I don't know the answer but here's a wild guess: did you try `?`? As in `href="...dosbatch.bat?para1"`.

Answer (score 4):

Links in HTML trigger your browser to fetch a file, and either render it if necessary (HTML, SVG, images, etc.) or prompt for a download for anything else. Links in HTML are not like a shell; you can't pass shell arguments to a file assuming it will be executed.